# Sending push notification to Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

How do I send push notifications to users who installed my Chrome extension?

Comment: I use WebSocket to send the notification to the extension and use [chrome.notifications](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications) API to display the required message in the notification. Here are some answers that may help you - [Push Notification | Is websocket mandatory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31035467/push-notification-is-websocket-mandatory) and [How to send push notifications to web application and browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47291391/how-to-send-push-notifications-to-web-application-and-browser)